# Dont start automatic transmition

Tags: hyperlink, playback, m3u8

I have an m3u8 link in stream that appears on.

ES: Liga de campeones M+ | Stream Id: ES-022 | Broadcasting 0.01x

When I play, the image does not appear, leaving the notice that it will play automatically.
I tested the link in VLC and it works perfectly, what could it be?

With other link haven't this problem...
Thank you !!

Try change the link and OK work.
Test in VLC and the m3u8 work OK.